# Reading local XML file from browser using javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, html5-filesystem

I am writing an html page for myself(*I do not want to use a webserver*) where I need to read an XML file (*on the same folder as the .html file*) and parse the data from it. The name of the file is known and not dynamic. Now, I am aware that due to restrictions browsers do not allow **Cross origin requests** on Ajax calls because of security restrictions. So it seems my only option is **FileSystem API.**

Could anyone help me out with the code for the same please?

**In short**
1. Read xml file from javascript once the page loads in the browser .
2. The name of the XML file is known and is on the same directory level.
3. How to  use the **FileSystem API** for reading the file and parsing the XML

**Constraints**
1. I dont want to use a web-server for the page(*since it is just a single page app*).
2. I dont want to use any javascript libraries(*like jQuery etc*).
3. Also I dont want to tweak chrome by adding the flags.
4. It is alright if the solution works only on chrome.

Thanks

Comment: You're saying that the XML file is local, so why not use Ajax? Local files doesn't have cross origin request policy.

Comment: @AbraarArique The javascript I am using is function `loadXMLFile(filename)
    {
     xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
     xhttp.open("GET",filename,false);
     xhttp.send();
     return xhttp.responseXML;
    }` But I am getting the following error _XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/Desktop/routeList.xml. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource._